# I'm getting Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now, not sure why?

Tags: php, mysqli

Not sure why I'm getting "Commands out of sync". Any reasons why?

This is my code:

```
// First we check if the email and code exists...
if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['code'])) {
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT activation_code FROM accounts WHERE email = ?')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['email']);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // Account exists with the requested email
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            if ($row['activation_code'] != $_GET['code']) {
                if ($stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE accounts SET activation_code = ? WHERE email = ?')) {
                    // Set the new activation code to 'activated', this is how we can check if the user has activated their account.
                    $newcode = 'activated';
                    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $newcode, $_GET['email']);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    echo 'Your account is now activated! You can now <a href="index.html">login</a>!';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'The account is already activated.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'The account doesn\'t exist!';
        }
    }
}
```

Tried googling with no results...